# Regarding navigation of AppcompactAtvity to Fragment issue

Tags: javascript, java, android, navigation, fragment

I have an Activity called login and in that activity i have a button support

when i am click the support button it should be navigates to an supportFragment.

I wrote below code to navigate to fragment.

@Override
public void run() {

```
                                                 supportLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onClick(View view) {
                                                         Intent supportIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SupportFragment.class);
                                                         startActivity(supportIntent);
                                                     }
                                                 });
```

But it shows below error:

### **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class......... have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

But we couldn't include frgment in manifestfile ...Then how can i navigate appcompatActivity to Fragment..................

Please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

From Activity you can navigate only to Activity, **not** to Fragment. So you need to navigate to another Activity, which should show the SupportFragment fragment